# Keeping Canvas size bigger than window

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Well, question is simple. Hot to achieve that my canvas(i.e. resolution 15000 * 10000 ) can be draggable in the window(i.e 1680*1050)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612678.aspx):

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Canvas Width="15000" Height="10000">
                ...
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Do you know maybe how to make scroolviewer zoomable(in/out) ?

Comment: You might set the [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) or [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property, e.g. to a [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx).